# Problem with the FD package, in the function "functcomp"

Tags: r, matrix

I have a problem with this script, can you gimme advice??
I don't why the matrix "a" (abund) is not recognized as a matrix

````
> trait<-read.table("C:\\R\\functional\\rasgo_1.txt",header=T)
> trait
  species hmax   dens  aleaf ldcm    sla
1     sp1  9.5 0.4646 120.52 0.44 123.24
2     sp2 22.0 0.5459  27.82 0.67 226.79
3     sp3 17.0 0.6213 100.21 0.42 143.42
> abund<-read.table("C:\\R\\functional\\sp_1.txt",header=T)
> abund
  species  sp1   sp2   sp3
1 sitio_1 6.59 65.55 23.56
> cero <- gowdis(trait)
> cero
          1         2
2 0.9064710          
3 0.5156626 0.7445331
> uno <- functcomp(trait, abund)
Error in functcomp(trait, abund) : 'a' must be a matrix.
> dos <- dbFD(trait, abund)
Error in dbFD(trait, abund) : Different number of species in 'x' and 'a'.
> dbFD(x= trait, a= abund, w.abun = TRUE, stand.x = TRUE, m= "min", 
+      calc.CWM = TRUE)
Error in dbFD(x = trait, a = abund, w.abun = TRUE, stand.x = TRUE, m = "min",  : 
  Different number of species in 'x' and 'a'.```
````

Comment: `abund`, `trait` are `data.frame` and not `matrix`.  convert to matrix wth `as.matrix` and check if that helps. thanks